# Null pointer exception with OutboundSseEvent in a server sent event service

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, server-sent-events, eventsource

I am trying to set up server sent events in a Java server with the OutboundSseEvent class. I'm not sure why my code keeps throwing a null pointer exception. I am using these tutorials as reference.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-jax-rs-sse and https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.ws.rs.sse.OutboundSseEvent

```
@Path("ssetest")
public class SSETestService extends SecureService {

    private Sse sse;

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces("text/event-stream")
    public void SSETestService(@Context Sse sse, SseEventSink sseEventSink)
            throws InterruptedException, IllegalArgumentException {
        OutboundSseEvent stringEvent = sse.newEventBuilder()
                .name("ping")
                .data("hello world").build();
        sseEventSink.send(stringEvent);
    }

}
```

On the client side...

```
    testSSE() {
      console.log("in testSSE()");
      const evtSource = new EventSource(
        "http://localhost:8081/api/ssetest/test"
      );
      evtSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log("received message");
        console.log("event.data: " + event.data);
      };
      evtSource.addEventListener("ping", function(event) {
        console.log("event.data: " + event.data);
        console.log("received ping event");
      });
      evtSource.onerror = function(err) {
        console.error("EventSource failed:", err);
      };
    }
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The instance sse is null. For litmus like test, you can print sse to see. If you using Spring framework `private Sse sse;` should be autowired as follows

```
@Autowired
private Sse sse;
```

I think the parameter `@Context Sse sse` should be removed as you have already defined in the class.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using the Spring framework. I updated the link for the guide that I am following. <https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-jax-rs-sse>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where exactly your null pointer occurs, but in my case it was because injection of the `Sse` and `SseEventSink` instances failed. In that case, an implementation of the SSE feature is missing on your classpath. You could use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-sse</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Furthermore, you need to make sure that your servlet allows asynchronous communication by enabling that setting, e.g.:

```
@WebServlet(... asyncSupported = true, ...)
...
public class MyServlet {
...
```